# $or in mongo not using index scan

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation

I am trying to make an aggregation pipeline which has its first stage a $or query but when I explained the aggregation execution the mongo is not using index scan?

The query that I was trying is

```
pipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [activeTill: Date.now(), deleteReason: CONSTANT.NOT_HAPPY]
        }
    }
];
```

Here I have made an index on the field `deleteReason` but not on `activeTill`.

Finally I found the way. See at the answer.

Comment: Your answer is kind of misleading. Can you edit your question to include the query that you are running?

Answer (score 0):

in `$or` query, mongo will use Index scan only when all fields which you are searching in the `$match` stage have their index already made.
If even one of the query `key` does not have `index` then mongo will use `collscan` (which we should avoid).

What I did, is I kept the key which does not have index outside the `$or` body and putting all other inside `$or`. In my use case, it worked.